# What does raring to rip mean?

Tags: meaning

> Peter McVries was 61. Hank Olson was 70. He was with the Major longer than the rest. The Major laughed at something Olson said and clapped him on the back. “I told him to keep a lot of money on short call,” Olson said when he came back. “And he told me to give ’em hell. Said he liked to see someone who was **raring to rip**. Give ’em hell, boy, he said. - The Long Walk, Stephen King

I tried to look it up and there’s the phrase - raring to go - which seems to mean excited to go. By analogy, raring to rip means excited to rip? But then, what does rip mean here exactly? Doesn’t feel like tearing up a sheet of paper..

Comment: The context should really be more surrounding text, and the title and author of the book or article from which you took the text.

Comment: ***raring to rip*** strikes me as a "mash-up" of well-established [***raring to go***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-raring-to-go) *(very eager to start doing something)* and *[ready to] [**let rip***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/let-rip) *(do something forcefully and without trying to control yourself)*.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rip): ***rip 2 :** to rush headlong*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is slang, and so rather casual.

There is a slang meaning of "rip" which is "To move or act quickly" (wiktionary). It might be related to the surfer slang sense, meaning "surf well".  So the expression "raring to rip" is a slang variant of "raring to go". But it isn't in general use.

Comment: There is also the fairly common slang expression "let 'er rip" meaning "start": or "go". That may be a source here.

Comment: It looks like casual conversation, probably among characters in a novel. I'm guessing - Stephen King?

Comment: To 'let rip' is to 'do something vigorously or without restraint'.

Answer (score 1):

to be raring [to do something]

Merriam Webster:

raring: adjective

Definition of raring
: **full of enthusiasm or eagerness**
ready and raring to go

to rip from ripper

An accomplished skier who knows exactly what they are doing on the mountain. They ‘rip’ up the slopes with their skills.

[ripper_rip_skiing](https://www.inghams.co.uk/ski-holidays/ski-holiday-types/ski-holidays-for-beginners/a-z-glossary-of-ski-slang-and-trail-talk)

So, in snowboarding, surfing and skateboarding:
He really rips. = He is doing the particular move/moves really well.

Frothy to learn about surfing? Don’t be surf-stoked. The sport’s language really rips.
[rips](https://www.latimes.com/sports/story/2019-08-03/us-open-language-surfing-world-surf-league-wsl)
Meaning: It really is cool and takes off.